# Can one teach VMware player to autostart multiple VMs?

Tags: vmware-player

I would like to use the latest free version of VMware Player (to my knowledge v7.1.4) to autorun **two** VMs whenever my Windows machine starts up.
I found the option to start a VM automatically by placing a "shortcut" with the commandline 
  "<path-to-VMware-player> -X <path-to-VM's-.vmx-file>"
into the Startup-folder and that works fine, except that - if I put **two** such shortcuts into the Startup-folder - it also starts VMware Player twice. I would prefer to have **one** copy running only which executes **both** VMs.

Any idea anyone how one can achieve that?